# Trying to retrieve index from Array using loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I made a program which stores movie names, hour and time of showing.
I saved the details inputted to arrays and then saved the arrays by getter and setter methods as a record.

In my final method i attempt to use a for loop to print out the details stored in the records but constantly get errors.

Any help to where the issue is would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Demonstrates usage of loops/adt/gettersetters

import java.util.Scanner;

class movies {
    public static void main(String[] p) {
        Movie m = new Movie();

        int[] screenn = new int[4];
        int[] namee = new int[4];
        int[] hourr = new int[4];
        int[] minn = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            screenn[i] = i + 1;
            String moviename = input("Film for screen " + (i + 1));
            namee[i] = moviename;
            int moviehour = inputint("what hour does it start?");
            hourr[i] = moviehour;
            int moviemin = inputint("what min does it start?");
            minn[i] = moviemin;
        }
        sethour(m, namee);
        setmin(m, minn);
        setscreen(m, screen);
        setname(m, namee);

        showtime(m);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //Getter Method
    public static String[] getname(Movie m) {
        return m.name;
    }

    public static int[] getscreen(Movie m) {
        return m.screen;
    }

    public static int[] gethour(Movie m) {
        return m.hour;
    }

    public static int[] getmin(Movie m) {
        return m.min;
    }

    //Setter Method
    public static Movie sethour(Movie m, int[] hour) {
        m.hour = hour;
        return m;
    }

    public static Movie setmin(Movie m, int[] min) {
        m.min = min;
        return m;
    }

    public static Movie setname(Movie m, String[] name) {
        m.name = name;
        return m;
    }

    public static Movie setscreen(Movie m, int[] screen) {
        m.screen = screen;
        return m;
    }

    public static String input(String message) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        print(message);
        String answer = scanner.nextLine();
        return answer;
    }

    public static String print(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        return message;
    }

    public static int inputint(String message) {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(input(message));
        return number;
    }

    public static void showtime(movie m) {
        print("Cineworld Movies For Tonight");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            print("");
            print(m.screen[i]);
            print(m.movie[i]);
            print(m.hour[i]);
            print(m.min[i]);
        }
    }
}

class Movie {
    String[] name = new String[4];
    int[] hour = new int[4];
    int[] min = new int[4];
    int[] screen = new int[4];
}
```

Comment: Your code is broken from the get-go. The Movie class should most definitely not hold arrays. Instead it should hold a single String and four ints, all private fields, with constructor getters and setters.

Comment: Also when asking about "constantly get errors", it would be wise to show your error messages in your question. But for this project, you will want to scrap this code and start over with a better Movie class.

Comment: ...........hello?

Comment: Try to format your source code properly - if you are using an IDE, let it do it for you. ADT and _accessors_ (_getters_&_setters_) don't mesh in my book.

Comment: thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting your assignment wrong. According to OOP The Movie class should store Movie's properties (name, hour, mins, etc) and then on your MainProgram you should store an array of movies. How you create and the usage of these objects is not concern of the class it self. Having said that i re-implemented your mainProgram to:

1. Ask for each (4) movie attributes.
2. Create the movie.
3. add it to a list of movies.
4. for each movie (4) print its properties.

### MovieClass:

```
public class Movie
{
    String name;
    int hour , min , screen;

    public Movie ( )
    {
        super ( );
    }


    public Movie ( String name , int hour , int min , int screen )
    {
        super ( );
        this.name = name;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.min = min;
        this.screen = screen;
    }



    public String getName ( )
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName ( String name )
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getHour ( )
    {
        return hour;
    }

    public void setHour ( int hour )
    {
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public int getMin ( )
    {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin ( int min )
    {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public int getScreen ( )
    {
        return screen;
    }

    public void setScreen ( int screen )
    {
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Movie [name="   + name + ", hour=" + hour + ", min=" + min + ", screen=" + screen
                + "]";
    }



}
```

### MainProgram:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MainProgram
    {

        public static void main ( String [ ] args )
        {
            List < Movie > movieList = new ArrayList < Movie > ( );

            for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++ )
            {

                int screen = i;
                String name = inputString ( "Film for screen "+(i));
                int hour = inputInt ("what hour does it start?");
                int min = inputInt ("what min does it start?");

                Movie movie = new Movie ( name , hour , min , screen );
                movieList.add ( movie );
            }

            print("Cineworld Movies For Tonight");

            for( Movie movie : movieList)
            {
                print ( "" );
                print ( Integer.toString ( movie.getScreen ( ) ));
                print (movie.getName ( ));
                print (Integer.toString ( movie.getHour ( ) ));
                print ( Integer.toString ( movie.getMin ( ) ));
            }

        }

        public static String inputString ( String message )
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner ( System.in );
            print ( message );
            String answer = scanner.nextLine ( );
            return answer;
        }

        public static String print ( String message )
        {
            System.out.println ( message );
            return message;
        }

        public static int inputInt ( String message )
        {
            int number = Integer.parseInt ( inputString ( message ) );
            return number;
        }


    }
```

**Note:** as you can see i re-used some of your static methods but if you need something else you have to implement it by yourself.

### I/O Example:

```
Film for screen 1
The Shawshank Redemption
what hour does it start?
19
what min does it start?
30
Film for screen 2
The Godfather
what hour does it start?
20
what min does it start?
15
Film for screen 3
The Godfather: Part II
what hour does it start?
20
what min does it start?
30
Film for screen 4
The Dark Knight
what hour does it start?
21
what min does it start?
15
Cineworld Movies For Tonight

1
The Shawshank Redemption
19
30

2
The Godfather
20
15

3
The Godfather: Part II
20
30

4
The Dark Knight
21
15
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your help.